# Querybuilder Eloquent won't delete record from model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried creating a universal delete function in 3 ways.

```
function DeleteByID($table, $id){
1.    DB::table("$table")->delete("$id");
2.    DB::table("$table")->find("$id")->delete();
3.    DB::table("$table")->where('id', '=', "$id")->delete();
}
```

I'm using ajax to send the request to an Ajax Controller class, which sends it to the according controller class of the specific subject. Everything goes fine with the ajax request, it does what it should do. But deleting something from the table doesn't work.

And yes, I am putting the right table names into the $table parameter when I'm calling the `DeleteByID($table, $id)` function.

#### Update 1

removed every double `""`  from the ajax request to the call of the delete function.

`DB::table($table)->where('id', '=', $value)->delete();`

Is what it is now. Still doesn't work.

#### Update 2

This triggers the DeleteRole function. This will open a modal, asking if you are sure you want to delete the record. there will be another button with `onclick="DeleteRole(this.id, true)"` with ofcourse the id send with it.

```
<a id="{{$role->id}}" onclick="DeleteRole(this.id, false)">
     <button class="btn btn-neutral btn-icon btn-round" data-toggle="modal" 
     id="{{$role->id}}" data-target="#rolesModalDelete">
          <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgba(185,14,22,0.81)">clear</i>
     </button>
</a>
```

AJAX Request:

```
function DeleteRole(id, bool){
    let contentModal = $('#DeleteRoleContent');
    if(bool === false){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/DeleteRole',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                const token = jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                if (token) {
                    return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                }
            },
            data: {
                roleID: id,
                popup: bool,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                contentModal.empty();
                contentModal.append(data);
            }
        });
    }else if (bool === true){
        let row = $('#' + id);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/DeleteRole',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                const token = jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                if (token) {
                    return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                }
            },
            data: {
                roleID: id,
                popup: bool,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                row.empty();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

#### Update 3

The `if` statement where it checks if the `$_POST['popup']` is true or not, was ignored. Changed it, so the deletion works now. But now the succes handler won't be called. the ajaxrequest returns 200 OK.

```
    public function RoleDelete()
    {
    if($_POST['roleID']){
        if($_POST['popup'] == 0){
           $htmlObject = $this->roleController->GetData($_POST['roleID']);
           echo json_encode($htmlObject);
        } else {
            if($_POST['roleID'] !== null) {
                $this->db->DeleteByID('rollen', $_POST['roleID']);
            } else {
                echo json_encode('ID is null');
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode('Geen gegevens gevonden, is het record al verwijderd? AC 256;');
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the double quotes.

Comment: I am 99% sure `$table, $id` are coming null. Can you `dd($table, $id)`` pls

Comment: Also, post your code where you do your Ajax call

Comment: $table shouldn't be null. Since I defined that here:
`$this->db->DeleteByID("rollen",  $roleID);`
$roleID shouldn't be null either, since I'm checking the `$_POST` if it is set. if not it should give an error message.

Comment: I think in PHP `$var === "$var"`, so removing the quotes doesn't change anything!? As long as `$var` is already a string obviously.

Comment: Since your code does not return any error, `$id` must be the one retuning null. Please check that

Comment: How can I check that @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz?

Comment: Where you do `$this->db->DeleteByID("rollen", $roleID);` make sure `$roleID` is not null.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Edited the code, added the function with the null check in the answer. I tried it with the null check, also didn't work.

Comment: I think `if($_POST['popup'] !== true)` is being ignored. I just dumped the response data, in the first ajax and then the 2nd request. It both dumps the `$htmlObject`

Comment: I don't think request variables like your `$_POST['roleID']` can ever be null at all. Usually they are always strings. When it's provided (PHP function `isset` returns true) without any value it should be an empty string and not null. So I suggest using the php function `empty` to check that like `if (!empty($_POST['roleID'])) ...`. Also I'd never call a variable `bool`, even if that is not a reserved keyword in JavaScript  :)

Comment: So instead of assuming your values are correct and not null, why don't you print them out to verify that, e.g. simply with `var_dump($_POST)`; (not JSON)

Comment: @xander, The bool is just a quick testing variable :P. I added the empty() function. And apparently the `if` statement I mentioned earlier, was indeed ignored. I changed the `true/false` to `1/0` now it deletes the record. But sadly now, it does not run the `row.empty();` code.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Did you analyse the AJAX request with your browser's network tool? YOu can see if it's really successful or what is returned etc. or I don't know why the success handler is not called in your code...

Comment: In Firebug. It returns: `200 OK 103ms` @xander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement where it checks if the $_POST['popup'] is true or not, was ignored. Changed it, so the deletion works now. But now the succes handler won't be called. the ajaxrequest returns 200 OK.

```
public function RoleDelete(){
   if($_POST['roleID']){
      if($_POST['popup'] == 0){
         $htmlObject = $this->roleController->GetData($_POST['roleID']);
         echo json_encode($htmlObject);
      } else {
        if($_POST['roleID'] !== null) {
            $this->db->DeleteByID('rollen', $_POST['roleID']);
        } else {
            echo json_encode('ID is null');
        }
      }
   } else {
    echo json_encode('Geen gegevens gevonden, is het record al verwijderd? AC 256;');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

Do not use **""** for variable

```
1.    DB::table($table)->delete($id);
2.    DB::table($table)->find($id)->delete();
3.    DB::table($table)->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: Edited my question. removed the `""` from everything leading up to the delete function. Sadly didn't work.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Did you get proper value in $table and $value?

Comment: As in the value's are not null? Yeah, they're not null, they're filled with the correct values, Table has the correct table name and the correct ID is posted with the ajax request. @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if this comes off as a "make sure it's plugged in" kind of answer, but sometimes the simple stuff is the easiest to overlook, especially when you're tunnel-visioned on the code.  That said, are you sure your DB credentials actually have delete-permissions?

Comment: Yeah, credentials are OK, I can delete other records in tables. I fixed it. It deletes the record now. But now the ajaxcall won't run the succes handler. But the request returns 200 OK @Claymore